# page not loading in uiwebview storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I am trying to call a method from another `UIViewController` which takes in a string(url) as parameter and opens it in `UIWebView`. Below is the code of the `IBAction` in the `UIViewController` class:

```
-(IBAction)dashboardButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"dashboard" sender:self];
    Dashboard *db = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashboard"];
    [db openDashboard:@"http://www.google.com"];
}
```

the method that takes in the url string is in another class called DashBoard:

```
-(void)openDashboard:(NSString *) url {
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
}
```

I do not get any error, but the `UIWebView` is always blank.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you set the `UIWebView` delegate? Does `openDashboard:` actually get called?

Comment: I haven't set the delegate for UIWebview. yes it does get called.

Answer (score 0):

Check

1. self.myWebView  outlet connected
2. self.myWebView  get reinitialized anywhere after this loading

EDIT.

Ok the reason may be you are setting the url and loading in the webview ,But it is not initialized yet since the view is **not yet loaded** from nib.Pass the url string and store in an instance variable and in viewDidLoad method set the loadRequest with the value in instance variable

Define an instance variable

```
NSString *_urlToLoad;
```

.m

```
-(void)openDashboard:(NSString *) url {
    _urlToLoad =[url copy];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_urlToLoad]]];
}
```

Comment: @HassanZaheer : Updated the answer ,Try it

Comment: how do I pass the url string if the next view is a uinavigationcontroller?

Comment: I have done that. But I am getting the error unrecognized selector sent to instance